# Access column of dataframe by index for validation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below piece of code works perfectly fine for column name 'AType'

```
df=df[df['AType'].isin(['P','C'])]
```

but instead of mentioning as `df['AType']` can I do above validation as column number

```
df=df[df.columns[7].isin(['P','C'])]
```

It is raising error

```
 df=df[df.columns[7].isin(['P','C'])]
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Need to do column validation on basis of column number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.iloc` is the integer-location based indexer.

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, 7].isin(['P','C'])]
```

Comment: nice addition, this should be the ideal way of solving this , slicing `df.columns` is not really required..!!

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the key you receive after `df.columns[7]` to the dataframe to obtain the series to be able to use `isin`

```
df=df[df[df.columns[7]].isin(['P','C'])]
```

The code:

```
df.columns[7]
```

This returns a string value. Whereas

```
df[df.columns[7]]
```

Returns a series which has the attribute `isin`